# Best way to park an automatic car on a slope without cause damage to the gear box

Tags: transmission, parking

Let s say i want to park my car on a sloppy road with out applying pressure on the automatic gear box.

The approach i m currently use is the below:

- Complete stop the car by pressing the foot brake (using D gear)
- Continue pressing the foot brake and apply the handbrake/e brake (using D gear)
- Release the foot brake (using D gear)
- Lastly, press again foot brake and move from D to P

Is this the correct way to part the car in a sloppy road without damaging the gear box?

Any help or tips will greatly appreciate.

Comment: The obvious you missed is turning the front wheels towards the kerb.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for the point. what i want to improve is anything relate with the gearbox & the handbrake/e brake.

Comment: What do you think you will cause damage to the gearbox, if that is what you are concerned about?

Comment: @HandyHowie the reason i post is to confirm if this is the correct what to part on a slope. Before this technique i used to press foot brake until the car stops, move  from D to P, release the foot break and establish e brake. However, when i try to un park the car it was very difficult to shift from P to D gear and as soon i manage to do it it was sound very strange.

Comment: If this is all about "technique", this question is off-topic for the site. Driving technique questions are not a fit for this Stack.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦the question is about to find the best way to avoid damages on the gearbox which i think is part of car maintenance.

Comment: It's no problem with manual transmission because depressing the clutch disengages the engine from the gearbox, but with auto transmission I've had your problem. I have used Park as the primary brake on a hill where the extra load can make it difficult to get out of Park. Stop the car, keep the footbrake depressed, select Neutral, apply the handbrake to full extend, test whether it is holding by easing off the footbrake, then engage Park. The gearbox lock obtained from Park will act as an emergency brake if the handbrake fails to hold.

Comment: Besides it being about "technique", it is also going to be fraught with a LOT of opinion. My "best" way to do something is not going to be someone else's "best" way. Really, I'm not seeing a lot of redeeming value to this question. I appreciate what you're trying to figure out, however, it just isn't aligning with our site. I'll leave it up to the site members to decide, but I have no problem being the 5th vote to close this.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 to be honest i feel very grateful when i m facing an issue/dilemma and i ask people to get them opinion/solution and have a conversation especially if this person is a mechanic for 35 years. Could you please share your experience and knowledge on this to avoid damaging the pawl?

Comment: I understand your thinking and can appreciate it ... the issue is, SE/SO isn't about opinion, but fact/truth. A conversation is something we can do on [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop), but here it should be about getting to the bottom line. While opinion sometimes plays a role, that role should be a minor role, not the headliner for an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you stop the car and put it in park and then release foot brake before engaging park brake you will cause the transmissions parking pawl to bear the force. This can cause shifting out of park difficult.
Either of the other two methods you mentioned will be acceptable. They will relieve most of the pressure from the parking pawl. The pressure will be absorbed through the brakes.

Answer (score 1):

Bruhhhhhhh its an automatic transmission. Just throw it in park and pull the hand brake and youre good. youre not gonna hurt anything. youre not gonna stress anything. For years i didnt have a park brake on my Ranger that weights 4000 pounds. It was a manual and i would just leave it in gear no matter what. It didnt do any damage and the entire weight is resting on the engine compression and 1st gear.

These things are built to withstand it when theyre designed.

You can also just put it in park and youre good.